# SAX parser is not working in windows?

Tags: java, xml

i have multiple xml files named media01.xml, media02.xml and so on.
I have written one java code which parses this xml file and fetches its table name and renames xml file. eg: media01--> Records.xml, media02 --> Info.xml and so on.
Part of that code is as follows:

```
 File inputFile = new File(path+File.separator+"media0"+xmlval+".xml");
     if(inputFile.exists())
     {
         try{
         SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
         SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
         aaaa a= new aaaa();
         saxParser.parse(inputFile, a);  
         String abc = aaaa.nsList();
         File dest = new File(path+File.separator+abc+".xml");
         inputFile.renameTo(dest);
         xmlval++;
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             System.err.println(""+e);
         }
     }
```

and the function which i am calling is:

```
class aaaa extends DefaultHandler {
 boolean bFirstName = false;
 boolean bLastName = false;
boolean loc = false;
 String name = null;
static String ans;


 @Override
 public void startElement(String uri,String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
  throws SAXException {
  if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("table")) {
     name = attributes.getValue("name");
  }
  if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("row")){     
  } 
  ans=name;
 }
 public static String nsList(){   
   return ans;
}
 }
```

i deployed my project on server and when i run the project from ubuntu OS then the xml file names are getting changed but the same when i am running from windows then its not renaming the files. what might be the issue?
Pls help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your filepath, is it writable?

Comment: Is there en exception thrown somewhere? Have you checked the output (in your console, shell...)?

Comment: Did you realize the the line `if(qName.equalsIgnoreCase("row")){     
  } ` does absolutely nothing?

Comment: ok... and its not throwing any exceptions

Answer (score 0):

i don't thin it is a Parser problem since there is no problem and SAXParser is used by so many projects that depend on SAX to parse their configuration file such as Spring , jsf i think and so many others so it is unlikely to be a saxproblem so the problem can be i your call to

```
File dest = new File(path+File.separator+abc+".xml");
inputFile.renameTo(dest);
```

which is platform dependent instruction you better check if the renaming was done successfully by doing like this

```
File dest = new File(path+File.separator+abc+".xml");
boolean renameSuccess=inputFile.renameTo(dest);
System.out.println("renaming "+renameSuccess?"succeeded":"failed");
```

Comment: debugging can be done in localhost and in localhost its working

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems I could encounter when deploying an application tested on a system to another system is that path and file names are case sensitive on Unix-like system. It is possible that your file already existed on your target system  but with a different case. Anyway, as achabahe mentioned it, you should check your return value when you rename a file.

Another remark, path separators are system dependent but generally Java doesn't make any problem. You can for example use '/' in a Windows path. I just would suggest you to instantiate `File` objects this way:

```
File myFile = new File(myPath, myFileName);
```

This is so easier to read and system-independent.

I also suggest you to trace if you actually open the source file. By the way can't you run it in debug mode?